# Turn Startup Disk Creator USB into primary drive

Tags: iso

I used startup disk creator to creatr a USB drive and now I want to use it as a regular parition. Is there a way just to turn it into a regular drive? I want to install Ubuntu on the same drive I have the installer ISO on.

Answer (score 0):

You would be more successful installing from, say, a Live DVD or bootable DVD to the USB drive you'd like to use as if you were doing a normal installation to an internal hard drive. Just change the install location to that USB drive.

A bit of a warning, though: USB drives are far slower than a traditional hard drive, so your performance will not be very good.

Comment: You could also use another live USB. Like boot from one USB and install to another.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use boot from USB which is why I need to do this in the first place.